# How do I make SAM progress?

Tags: ios, jetpack-joyride

I used to have my phone in spanish, but then I got the new update and changed my phone to english, and ever since then SAM won't progress. It always stays at day 1 and because of that I can get SAM every single run I do. It's great being able to get the extra 500 coins every game, but how do i make it move on to the next day rewards?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get SAM rewards you must collect all three letters every day. If you do this for 5 days consecutively you *should* get the rewards.  If not then your problem is one of two things.

Its either some sort of internet connection issue as SAM will not function correctly if you have troubles connecting to the internet or your not collecting all the letters every day.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, I collect all three letters each day (and can actually collect all three letters multiple times a day) but it must be an internet thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect all the SAM letters every day for 7 days. Everyday you will get progressively better rewards, and on the 8th day the cycle will reset and you will start back up with the first reward.